# Synchronizing aws ssm parameter values in spring boot microservice

Tags: spring, spring-boot, microservices, spring-cloud

I have implemented spring boot microservice with *BootstrapConfiguration* to read aws ssm parameter, which will replace the matching entries within *application.properties*. If I start microservice, in logs, I can see the value of the property entry has been replaced by the value of a ssm param value. If I update ssm parameter value in aws, the new value is not getting reloaded/synchronized in microservice. I still see the old value. My requirement is how to read latest aws ssm parameter value in spring boot microservice without restarting. Appreciate your help.